# Shell script : Executing a long line

Tags: shell, split, command-line-arguments

I'm writing a shell script which run at the end a curl command posting a json data..This data is too long and when running the script, it can't run the full command ! I tried to split the lines but i get errors in json data !

N.B : I'm using embedded linux

Comment: Show the curl command.

Comment: curl http://xxxxxxxx --header 'Content-Type:application/json' --data '{"xxx":"'"$xxx"'","xxx":"'"$xxx"'","xxx":"'"$xxx"'","xxx":"'"$xxx"'","xxxx":"'"$xxx"'","xxx":"'"$xxxx"'","xxxx":{"xxxx":"'"$xxx"'","xxx":"'"$xxx"'","xxxx":"'"$xxx"'","xxx":"'"$xxx"'","xxx":"'"$xxxx"'","xxx":"'"$xxx"'", "xxxx":"'"$xxx"'","xxx":"'"$xxx"'"}'

Answer (score 0):

Can you write your JSON data to a file and call curl like:

```
curl "$URL" --header 'Content-Type:application/json' --data @data.json
```

Comment: i tried so, but didnt work also ! what should i write exactly in this file ? ('{xxxxxxxxxxxxx}') ?